# wordpress big imgage threshold to be applied based only on width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, image-scaling

WordPress scales large images with more than specific height or width.

```
function dg_big_image_size_threshold( $threshold ) {
    return 2000; // new threshold
}
add_filter('big_image_size_threshold', 'dg_big_image_size_threshold', 100, 1);
```

I have a applied this function to change the threshold. Now what I want is to make images scale based only on width not height. e.g If image has width more than 2000px than scaling should be applied no matter what the height is. e.g If height is 2500px and width is 1800px then no scaling should be done.

Answer (score 2):

`big_image_size_threshold` filter receive original image size as second parameter. You can you it to determine should you resize image or not.

```
add_filter('big_image_size_threshold', function( $default, $imagesize ){
    list($width, $height) = $imagesize;
    $width_max = 2000;

    if( $width > $width_max ) // if width over limit, resize
        return $width_max;

    return false; // no reisze
},10,2);
```

Comment: @az-rieil While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. - [Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation)